# How to find tag in table structure using jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnID" value='209' class="hdn" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnID" value='210' class="hdn" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnID" value='211' class="hdn" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a jQuery click event for the add buttons.

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function ($e) {
  // Need selector here that can find the hidden field (see above) that is found 
  // in the same td as the button that was clicked. For example, if the Add button
  // in the 2nd row was clicked then I need to find the hidden input that has 
  // the value of '210'.

  // Doesn't work... not sure why
  var hdn = $(this).siblings().next();
});
```

Thanks in advance for helping me through a thick moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
("#btnAdd").click(function ($e) {
   var hdn = $(this).parent().next().children('td input');
});
```

Comment: Well, I suppose it'd work, but there are actually another 5 or so columns that are in this table. I just left them out for the sake of clarity. But now you have me wondering if I could get Siblings() to work somehow...

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I ended up doing $(this).next() to get it work.